# Cleanup user input library .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, sanitization

Is there a .Net library which everyone uses to validate/cleanup user input from website. It seems like there are a lot of posts explaining which regex people use and when.  While I do like to reinvent the wheel quite frequently I draw the line at user input.

Mostly I am not worried about SQL injection, but rather am concerned about html inputs and inputs which I cannot imagine.  It would just put a smile on my face for it to work like this:

```
    string sanitizedInput = InputSanitizer.SanitizeInput(input, SanitizeOption.RemoveHTML 
| SanitizeOption.RemoveSQL);
```

Anyone have anything like this? (Thanks in advance)

Comment: Is your primary interest security or input formatting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest version of [AntiXSS](http://antixss.codeplex.com) has HTML sanitization functions that MS use internally.

Comment: See http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2009/09/19/MicrosoftAntiCrossSiteScriptingLibrary31.aspx for a quick tip / micro-overview.

Answer (score 0):

There's xVal:

http://www.codeplex.com/xval

and the Validator toolkit:

http://mvcvalidatortoolkit.codeplex.com/